# How to validate multi <h2> metatag values using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: webdriver, meta-tags

We are using Specflow with Selenium Webdriver, using C# Step Definition files.
I am testing a web page where we have one h1 tag but multi h2 & h3 tags.

The test in Specflow is written thus:

```
Scenario Outline: The H1 displays the correct value
Given I view the page <page> at url <url>
Then the h1 will read h1

Examples:
| page| url         | h1        |
| home| www.xyz.com | About xyz |
```

This test will be easy enough to run as there is only one h1 tag, and it should contain "**About xyz**".

But, the issue I have is that when testing for h2 & h3 tags, there are more than one of them, so am not sure how best to structure the test.

I could add multi h2 rows in the Examples table, but dont know how to code for this in the step definition file to assert the values. The test could fail as it cannot work out which h2 I need to validate, hence the question. 
Any help is much appreciated.

I have searched in loads of places for this type of query but found nothing. It must be so easy that no-one else has a problem except me!!

Thanks

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following to check if the h2 or h3 tag contains a certain phrase you're looking for:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h2[contains(., 'TEXT')]"));
```

All you need to do is replace the 'TEXT' with the phrase you're looking for, and it will return the element you want to you.

For instance, if you wanted to find 'About xyz' in any h1 on the page:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h1[contains(., 'About xyz')]"));
```

You could create a list of WebElements and use the driver.FindElements function so that you can create a collection of the headers on the page.  At this point, you can reference which occurrence you want to interact with by including an index like [1] after the last ')' like so:

```
driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//h1[contains(., 'About xyz')]"))[3];
```

If you don't want to have multiple elements, you'll need to fine tune the details you're looking for.